Can you start a legal-defense fund for an unnamed alleged criminal for a crime not yet committed?
It happens quite frequently when someone commits a crime that a fund is created in which people can contribute to the legal defense and commissary of the alleged perpetrator that committed the crime. Would it be legal to create a legal-defense fund for those alleged to have committed a crime not yet committed?

How would someone be alleged to have committed a crime that is still speculative?  And why would you want to do this?  I'd expect that some sort of incitement charge would be the biggest issue.  Which would turn on the question of whether this is something like "legal defense fund for anyone who assassinates (or attempts to assassinate) Pres Trump" or "legal defense fund for anyone accused of speeding".

@JustinCave There's criminal defense insurance, which is often part of professional insurance. Therefore, there's already funds to defend e.g. doctors committing criminal medical errors.

@user71659 I never thought about that. It would be exactly like gifting criminal defense insurance.

@user71659 - Sure.  Which is why it would be important to know the "why".  Buying legal insurance for a specific person that might or might not ever be charged with a crime is certainly legal.  Plenty of organizations have legal teams that come to the aid of people challenging particular laws (i.e. the NAACP employed a host of lawyers during the civil rights era to aid people charged with violating segregation laws).  A legal defense fund for anyone that murders the President is likely to create issues.

@JustinCave Why though? They deserve a fair trial too.

In 2016 Trump famously said, “If you see somebody getting ready to throw a tomato, knock the crap out of them. I promise you, I will pay for the legal fees.” (When one of his supporters later punched a protestor, he did not follow through on this promise, of course.) Reportedly, police in North Carolina considered whether to prosecute him for inciting violence, but decided against it. When he said it, violence could have been imminent, since his statement was made at a ...

... rally while a protestor was currently making themself heard. As I understand it, "incitement" is only a crime in the US if there is a risk of "imminent lawless action", since the First Amendment sets a high bar for the criminalisation of speech. So if that didn't count as incitement, then I doubt it would be incitement to propose a "bounty" defense fund in a context where the "bountied" crime wouldn't be imminent.

Frame challenge: when would it not be legal to set up a criminal defense fund?

DV for lack of any research effort.  Google "legal defense fund"... there is all kinds of information out there.

@littleadv since the crime has not been commited and it is not protecting a specific person, maybe it could be construed as somewhat inciting the crime. E.g. "I will pay $1M to defending anyone who is in the future accused of murdering Donald Trump."

@SJuan76 incitement may be illegal, but not the fund though, right?

There are many legal-defense funds set up prospectively, for as-of-yet unidentified and uncommitted offences or other legal actions.
As just one example of many, see the Repro Legal Defense Fund, which "provides financial support for people investigated or fighting charges related to their pregnancy or abortion."
